# ¿Hay algun plugin de cordova para las notficaciones push de iOS que este funcionando actualmente?

Tags: ios, firebase

Intenté hacer funcionar notificaciones push en iOS pero no funcionan. Estoy usando  el plugin **$cordovaPushV5** pero no llegan(configuré todos los certificados de APPLE y tambien en el proyecto de XCODE activé las notificaciones). Alguien puede darme una mano?
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: You're at the wrong version of Stack Overflow. This is the Official Site of Stack Overflow in Spanish, so, please, Translate your question or ask it in [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a que te pases por el [tour] y leas [ask], para que mejores tu pregunta, como tal tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y se basa en opiniones. Saludos